# Equivalent ways to study a semilinear parabolic equation as a perturbed abstract Cauchy problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, banach-spaces, operator-theory, parabolic-pde

I am considering the following abstract Cauchy problem on Banach space $X$:
\begin{cases}
u'(t)=Au(t)+\big(f(t)+Bu(t)\big),&t\in[0,T],\\
u(0)=x_0,
\end{cases}
Suppose $A$ generates an analyitc semi-group $S(t)$ on $X$, then under certain assumptions, we can study the wellposeness of the following integral equation for the original Cauchy problem:
\begin{equation}
u(t)=S(t)x_0+\int_0^t S(t-s)\big(f(s)+Bu(s)\big)\, ds.\tag{1}\label{eq:noper}
\end{equation}

However, we can also view $C=A+B$ as a perturbation of $A$, hence suppose $A+B$ also generates an analytic semi-group $T(t)$ on $X$, then we can also study
\begin{equation}
u(t)=T(t)x_0+\int_0^t T(t-s)f(s)\, ds.\tag{2}\label{eq:per}
\end{equation}

I hope to show the wellposedness of a mild solutions $u\in C([0,T];(D(A),\|\cdot\|_A)$ to \eqref{eq:noper} and \eqref{eq:per} should be equivalent, in the sense that a solution to \eqref{eq:noper} should also be a solution to \eqref{eq:per}, also conversely. Here $\|\cdot\|_A$ refers to the graph norm. I think it may be correct(at least with good assumptions for $x_0$ and $B$), since intuitively, they come from two different ways to interpret the same Cauchy problem.

For your information, the specific problem I am considering is $A$ be an elliptic  2nd order operator and $B$ be a first order operator.

I have read  Engel-Nagel' book, which presents the following form of a variation of parameters formula for perturbed semigroups, for some operator $B$,
$$T(t)x=S(t)x+\int_0^t S(t-s)BT(s)x\,ds,$$
but I failed to use it to show the desired result.

Is there any reference with rigorous arguments you can point out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive that the mild solution $u$ as given in (2) satisfies (1) from the connection between the semigroups $S$ and $T$ as you cited from the Engel-Nagel book (as a minor remark, there is an $x$ missing right before the $ds$): 
Just insert the cited formula into (2), re-arrange and interchange order of integration. A function satisfying (1) must be unique (use Gronwall's Lemma), so the mild solution as given in (2) is the unique function satisfying (1).

Please also recall that $B$ must be a bounded operator for the cited formula to be true!

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Following it, I have verified a mild solution given in (2) satisfied (1) using the cited formula. So I think conversely, just reversing the process, it should follow that a mild solution given in (1) should also satisfied (2). Hence if I should the cited formula holds and I can show the uniqueness of mild solution to one of them (in particular, I have show the uniqueness of solution to (2)), then the uniqueness of mild solution to the other should follow. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, basically. I think it is enough to observe that you need the same assumptions on your data to make both expressions (1) and (2) well-defined, so as soon as (1) is meaningful, the function defined in (2) is already the (unique, due to Gronwall) function satisfying (1).

Comment: > Please also recall that BB must be a bounded operator for the cited formula to be true!

This is certainly not true. All you need is that the integrand is a continuous function (of the variable $s$) from $\mathbb R_+$ to the space of bounded linear operators on $X$. Since the semigroup generated by $A$ is analytic, the formula could make sense even for unbounded $B$ if $B$ is relatively $A$-bounded.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Thanks for your remark. I found from Engel-Nagel book [page 168](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=one-parameter+semigroups+for+linear+evolution+equations+Show+that+the+variation+of+parameters+formulas&source=bl&ots=2QU74BbR3z&sig=qxdPSE9pzP9PFRCW2sDAl_I7U9Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDnZeKg8bMAhXkF6YKHd2OC28Q6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=one-parameter%20semigroups%20for%20linear%20evolution%20equations%20Show%20that%20the%20variation%20of%20parameters%20formulas&f=false) that the formula also holds for bounded operator $B$ on $D(A)$ with $x\in D(A)$.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo So let me make sure I understand your comments. What you are suggesting is that in my case, if $B$ is relatively $A$-bounded, then $A+B$ generates an analytic semigroup $T$ on $X$, hence $T(t)x\in D(A)$ for all $x\in X$. So by repeating Engel-Nagel's proof for the cited formula, in my case, the formula holds for $B\in L(D(A), X)$ with $x\in X$ even though $B$ is unbounded on $X$. Am I correct?

Comment: @JohnZHANG One has to be careful. What I am saying is that if $B$ is bounded from $D(A)$ to $X$ and $T(\cdot)$ is analytic, then $BT(\cdot)$ is a bounded operator on $X$, and of course so is $S(\cdot)$. Now, you *may* have enough information to conclude that the mapping $T(t-\cdot)BS(\cdot)$ (from $\mathbb R_+$ to the space of bounded linear operators on $X$) is integrable.